# How to require a an object property on one of two function arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a factory which returns a method. The factory can set a default `id`, in which case it is no longer required to be passed to the method.

Here is a simplified test case ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgY2AewE4gPJmAS2QOwGcoBeKAbwFgAoKKHAEwH4AuKfAVwFsAjCVGgF8aNUJCgBZCMAAWyBllwFiZKrXrM2nXvyEjqAMw74kefFAOIU6KAApk2M4TbwkaTI+UBKCjTqppDlRzLmk5BgA6Hhx8BltOABsEgBooByUiLz1qGiMTDKhQ2Xk7QmA4YAgXK3dFJ1T0pzYpYoVPTN91BGVgDVIoMoqICMYoAB8xtPbCEYY-KG6iZAThhOQAc1tGCJQAZWBUGM2vLPUAejOoAEUAVQBRXYAVAEkMADk2OQB3KAZkKGeUHWHDgqDg+Eq0FkFSg0N6owgAA8cGVCKkeCBCnAANZHAZBKEyGEAA0YxPmF3oxEI0jS5kGlSg4IYZzQdKmGUITGyQA))

```js
type FactoryOptions = {
  id?: number
}

type MethodOptions = {
  id?: number
}

function factory (options: FactoryOptions) {
  return method.bind(null, options)
}

function method (state: FactoryOptions, options: MethodOptions) {
  const id = state.id || options.id
  console.log(id.toString())
}
```

The `id.toString()` is just to trigger TypeScript to complain that `id` might be undefined at this point. The context of this question is [octokit/auth-app.js#5](https://github.com/octokit/auth-app.js/issues/5) which is more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two sides to this problem... the caller's side of `method()`, and the implementation of `method()`.  In TypeScript it's generally easier to make the type checker behave nicely for callers than it is to make it work inside implementations.

From the caller's side, we can make sure that `method` must be called with at least one of the two arguments containing a defined `id` property.  One way to do this is with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), and since that's the least crazy-looking solution I can come up with, that's what I'll show (the other solutions involve using unions of [tuple types as a rest parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions)):

```
type WithId = {
  id: number;
};

function method(state: FactoryOptions & WithId, options: MethodOptions): void;
function method(state: FactoryOptions, options: MethodOptions & WithId): void;
function method(state: FactoryOptions, options: MethodOptions) {
   // impl
}
```

Here you can either call the first or second call signature, and the implementation signature is hidden from the caller:

```
method({}, {}) // error
method({id: 1}, {}) // okay
method({}, {id: 1}) // okay
```

Inside the implementation, things are less pleasant.  There's no easy way to convince the compiler that a value of type `[number, number | undefined] | [number | undefined, number]` has a defined value at either the first or second element.  That is, the compiler doesn't see such a union as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), so checking the first element against `undefined` has no effect on what the compiler sees as the second union.  You  might be able to implement some kind of [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) for this, but that's overkill.

Instead, let's just accept that we are smarter than the compiler and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function method(state: FactoryOptions & WithId, options: MethodOptions): void;
function method(state: FactoryOptions, options: MethodOptions & WithId): void;
function method(state: FactoryOptions, options: MethodOptions) {
  const id = (typeof state.id !== "undefined"
    ? state.id
    : options.id) as number; // assert as number
  console.log(id.toString()); // okay now
}
```

Also note that I changed your check of `state.id` to use a ternary because `0` is falsy and `0 || undefined` is `undefined`.  I assume you mean for `id` to always be a number, which is guaranteed by the ternary check (which sidesteps the falsiness).

That might not be what you hoped for, but it's the best I can do.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgY2AewE4gPJmAS2QOwGcoBeKAbwFgAoKKHAEwH4AuKfAVwFsAjCVANw0AvkOo1QkKAFkIwABbIGWXAWJkqteszade-MaJo0AZh3xI8+KCcQp0ACmTYrhNvCRpMLtQEoKNHSochyo1lxyigwAdDw4+AwOnAA2yQA0UM6qRL6GxtSS0ADqOAoAkgykAVqMutx8giJipuaWBFARCkoOhMBwwBDudl4qrlAAZFAl5QwZWa5ssl3KPjlsAG7IjGJmFtkdkd29-YOww+ijanOrbjKHK9nEk9PyFb4bWww7rfudUT19AZDTwXG7XR6Le6XHLVOgINTAbRVByFZAmKDHAbRRhQACEJDIACJzAwICZ4hAGITAnQoEwMYCINiGDS6Gx5mpmf44MQ9A0xHC1MhkkzksgAOYORjRFAAZWAqHikt8uRE+T+3XIwgyWv8AHo9VB+Kg0DQNYlyLUoABGbUUYT6w3IADWcBAZvuDi1OqttsdmVd7vE1CAA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, much appreciated!

I wonder if there is a way to avoid the "as number" suffix? No biggie if not, that will work for the time being, I’m just wondering

Comment: That’s the type assertion that you need in order to tell the compiler that it cannot be undefined.  It can’t figure it out by itself.  If you want to do `if (typeof id === "undefined") throw new Error()` instead, that will work but is unnecessary runtime professing.

Comment: ahem, "unnecessary runtime PROCESSING".  Thanks, autocorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the excellent answer via `jcalz`, here is another ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgY2AewE4gPJmAS2QOwGcoBeKAbwFgAoKKHAEwH4AuKfAVwFsAjCVGgF8aNUJCgBZCMAAWyBllwFiZKrXrM2nXvyEjqAMw74kefFAOIU6KAApk2M4TbwkaTI+UBKCjTqppDlRzLmk5BgA6Hhx8BltOABsEgBooByUiLz1qGgRlYCgZOEIASQZSOxiwDmA2OHwQLzYqmvpickYtbj5UQVIAPig-KDEIZAN6fGrgCMYoAEISMgByYwYIAxiIBmWAbiGcw2NTAihQ2Xk7QmA4YAg2DC4cYAAeV2sPDMJU5cZl-tS6ScbAAShAAI4cHABBgvKQXBSeIj9JpQABuyEYuxoRhMGTOYUutmut3uUDBkOh2zeVnciicALSSOcUEezzhhMRXx+fxRbAxWJxx3x53CVxudxctPQ9OUgOZbHh4VlmX5mPKajoOAMtiKpTiJLuXh8mroUDyRGQCQgEQSyAA5sSJTbGBEUABlYCoGKO43Y9R9CAJQjQbV2PVlezM42+dR0C2EK02u2OoHKWaRD1en22P3DYTUAs0UXyWzkQSpctefYAehrUH4qDQxc5ZY0bAAjAAGKAViiCatQOtpADWLYRbb75HbUG7vcHw+QI6AA)) for your consideration.

```js
type FactoryOptions = {
  id?: number
}

type MethodOptions = {
  id?: number
}

function factory (options: FactoryOptions) {
  return method.bind(null, options)
}

const hasId = (input: any): input is {id: number} => 
  typeof input.id !== 'undefined'; 

function method (state: Omit<FactoryOptions, 'id'>, options: Required<MethodOptions>): void;
function method (state: Required<FactoryOptions>, options: Omit<MethodOptions, 'id'>): void;
function method (state: FactoryOptions, options: MethodOptions): void {
  if(hasId(state)) {
    console.log(state.id.toString());
  } else if (hasId(options)) {
    console.log(options.id.toString());
  }
}

method({}, {}); // error
method({ id: 10 }, {}); // ok
method({ }, { id: 10 }); // ok
```